# What is this error in Apple's "ZoomingPDFViewer" code example from CGContextDrawPDFPage <Error>: KSTFBB+Helvetica: FT_Load_Glyph failed: error 133

Tags: ios, cgpdf

I am looking at Apple's [ZoomingPDFViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) example (source available from link). And when it runs, it gives this error:

```
 ZoomingPDFViewer[5751] <Error>: KSTFBB+Helvetica: FT_Load_Glyph failed: error 133.
```

It happens on line `100` of `ZoomingPDFViewer`:

```
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
```

Does anyone have any idea about why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error comes from FreeType library that Apple uses to draw fonts.

It basically means that FreeType failed to load a glyph and that glyph will be substituted while drawing text.

This error doesn't seem to hurt anything and maybe safely ignored. Maybe an Apple engineer forgot to take out an NSLog() line. :-)